# White flash between videos

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this videos loading on a bootstrap modal. 
If you click one of the cars in the main page (link below) the video opens. The issue is between the videos. If you click "next" at the bottom of the page you (usually) get a white flash between the videos. I tried black backgrounds for pretty much everything, z-index but nothing.

This is the jQuery code snippet that controls the "player" inside the modal

```
jQuery('.startstop').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      var $video = jQuery('video', jQuery(this));
    $video[0].play();
});


jQuery('.startstop').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    var $video = jQuery('video', jQuery(this));
        $video[0].pause();
        $video[0].currentTime = 0;
});


jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var timer;

jQuery(window).on('mousemove', function () {
  jQuery('.modnavi-left, .modnavi, .mbutton').addClass('show');
  try {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  } catch (e) {}
timer = setTimeout(function () {
  jQuery('.modnavi-left, .modnavi, .mbutton').removeClass('show');
  }, 3000);
});


// CARS //

jQuery('#end').on('ended',function(){
  jQuery('#THECHALLENGE').modal('hide');
  jQuery('#HONDAMODE').modal('show');
});

jQuery(".next1").click(function() {
 jQuery('#THECHALLENGE').modal('hide');
});  

// ----_______
```

This is one of the modals:

```
<div id="THECHALLENGE" class="modal startstop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">    
  <div class="modal-content">      
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mbutton" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">X</span></button>
  <video id="end" poster="http://www.andreasgrassl.de/cdn/poster/andreas-grassl-director.gif" controls width="1280" height="720" preload="none">
    <source src="http://andreasgrassl.de/cdn/BMW_M4%20GTS_The%20Challenge.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
  <h4 class="modal-title">BMW – THE CHALLENGE <a class="next1 align-right modnavi" data-toggle="modal" href="#HONDAMODE">next</a></h4> 

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And this is one of the triggers

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2 col-xs-12">
  [caption id="attachment_23" class="zoomag" align="alignnone" width="500"]<a data-toggle="modal" href="#THECHALLENGE"><img src="http://grassl.lopezi.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/1_BMW_M4_GTS_The-Challenge_.jpg" alt="BMW - THE CHALLENGE" width="500" height="281" class="size-full wp-image-23" /></a> BMW - THE CHALLENGE[/caption]
</div>
```

[website](http://grassl.lopezi.biz/)

Comment: Not sure how you load the video's, but maybe you could try to load the video before you show the next modal, meaning  you'd set some timeinterval before showing the modal, but render the video into the modal already.

Comment: Update your answer with this code rather than linking us to your website. Also "setting a timer didn't work"  is not something I can go off on, because it does not tell me what you have attempted.

Comment: So why doesn't  the video play when you call this. Also, when do you execute this? We need the click handler for the "next" button, untill the code where you render the modal on the screen. Also give provide the markup that the selectors refer to so we can check if there's a discrepancy in that section.